# how to make this regular expression [^:]+(?=,|$) so it is not found (" ")

Tags: regex, jmeter, expression, extractor

I'm having a problem. I can not understand how to make this regular expression [`^:]+(?=,|$)` so it is not found (" ")

I need regex to pass access token without quotation marks this expression:

```
{"access_token":"UEaYoz4xgKQUyjHv9dg6nzaWN52jHbeGRymGVqdo6wd‌​WwXLjoxPydlNkXEOJYki‌​QpEXOHTo99Tn7i9Q-MHP‌​MFmnqmfLjel-0qVVpF1r‌​FxEiB_RtX3kMYm5-ihH7‌​OYB3aEzFvnQ_HsNevGlV‌​72AFKKJrhSP9V637SSYC‌​5MDzU4Wri0_uPW1VMuLu‌​q-IhtOPrSe0lqu86clal‌​ySuevFf5w_jcHPEm5xIx‌​R4pTzELfYluQiFS9JrAC‌​s5tF2d-WwkTZaYhjCf9M‌​Wx5JVqtMJC0x8shPvHZA‌​rH5Um1jpO12UHtRSU6P5‌​rP5VHuEk8AAQmDEv5EYh‌​59RI6jAWKtYRZMEBoJZO‌​UEbF9ZelPB4jYqpx4gsV‌​kP0GVJ57o_d3OiAllvOo‌​kY14u1GXZ3XN1fesOi89‌​srmatVf_J6ka50m9ilrW‌​tzMYWNq6vf2j-JgQA87R‌​80DTaRtCFfg"}
```

This part of access token need to pass without the quotes:

```
UEaYoz4xgKQUyjHv9dg6nzaWN52jHbeGRymGVqdo6wd‌​WwXLjoxPydlNkXE‌​OJYki‌​QpEXOHTo99Tn7‌​i9Q-MHP‌​MFmnqmfLjel‌​-0qVVpF1r‌​FxEiB_RtX‌​3kMYm5-ihH7‌​OYB3aEz‌​FvnQ_HsNevGlV‌​72AFK‌​KJrhSP9V637SSYC‌​5MD‌​zU4Wri0_uPW1VMuLu‌​q‌​-IhtOPrSe0lqu86clal‌‌​​ySuevFf5w_jcHPEm5xI‌​x‌​R4pTzELfYluQiFS9J‌​rAC‌​s5tF2d-WwkTZaYh‌​jCf9M‌​Wx5JVqtMJC0x8‌​shPvHZA‌​rH5Um1jpO12‌​UHtRSU6P5‌​rP5VHuEk8‌​AAQmDEv5EYh‌​59RI6jA‌​WKtYRZMEBoJZO‌​UEbF9‌​ZelPB4jYqpx4gsV‌​kP0‌​GVJ57o_d3OiAllvOo‌​k‌​Y14u1GXZ3XN1fesOi89‌‌​​srmatVf_J6ka50m9ilr‌​W‌​tzMYWNq6vf2j-JgQA‌​87R‌​80DTaRtCFfg
```

Comment: Can you post example code and desired output from the regex?

Comment: Is the underlying problem that you're trying to interpret JSON using regex? You should probably be using a JSON parser for this. [This blog post](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2014/06/12/parsing-json-responses-with-jmeter/) talks about different ways of parsing JSON using jmeter.

Comment: I updated your question based on your comments, and flagged them as obsolete.  Next time, please [edit] your questions - it needs to stand on its own, even without the comments.  And this is *still* very hard to understand.  If you find it hard to express your question in English, perhaps you should find a site where you can ask in your own language. (Guessing based on your name, though I know this is a stretch, perhaps you could try https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: So you want a regex to match the value of key `"access_token"`, excluding the quote?  Then why not simply do `"access_token"\s*:\s*"([^"]*)"` ? the value is captured in group 1

Answer (score 1):

You are making things over complicated, JMeter supports [Perl5-style regular expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html), it means you can make the quotation marks a part of the search pattern so they will be considered the left and right boundaries like:

```
"access_token":"(.+?)"
```

Going forward when it comes to JSON it makes more sense to use [JSON Path PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Path_PostProcessor) available since JMeter 3.0. The relevant [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) query will be as simple as:

```
$.access_token
```

To learn how to develop more complex JSONPath queries see [Advanced Usage of the JSON Path Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter) guide

Comment: You might still want to use `([^"]+)` in the regex.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean `[^: "{}]+` then you have to say so.  This matches any string which does not contain any of the four enumerated characters.  It will still match only the leftmost longest match, so you will need to anchor the match somehow.  Based on your example, I guess you are really looking for

```
[^:"[{}]+(?="?([},]))
```

which matches the longest-leftmost string of characters not in the character class which occur just before an optional double quote followed by either a closing brace or a comma.

As others already noted in comments, using regex to parse JSON is generally a very bad idea.  There are many corner cases where this will fail; for a start, the JSON could be split on multiple lines, so that the brace or the comma is not on the same line as the access token, and then extracting it by this regex will fail.